# Display the score of a quiz arranged by different sub-categories

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am struggling to find the best approach to display the result of a multiple choice quiz according to different categories. I am fairly new to JavaScript, and if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

As a bit of background info, different answers have different points (see below).

```
const energyQuestions = [
  {
     "question": "In summer, the temperature of your AC ?",
    "answer1": "+26℃",
    "answer1Total": "5",
    "answer2": "20-25℃",
    "answer2Total": "3",
    "answer3": "16-20℃",
    "answer3Total": "1"
  },
  {
   "question": "Will you turn off the screen when you are not using your PC ?",
    "answer1": "Often",
    "answer1Total": "5",
    "answer2": "Sometimes",
    "answer2Total": "3",
    "answer3": "Rarely",
    "answer3Total": "1"
  }
  ]
```

Currently, the total score of the quiz can display properly (see below), but I'm having a problem with displaying score arranged by different categories, like energyQuestions score, polutionQuestions score, etc.

```
 //Get value of selected radio
    const answerScore = Number(selectedOption.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('data-total'));

    ////Add the answer score to the score array
    score.push(answerScore);

    selectedAnswersData.push()


    const totalScore = score.reduce((total, currentNum) => total + currentNum);
```

Comment: I think you ommitted some relevant code from your post.

Comment: Show us some html, it's hard to picture what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you are structuring the data for the questions. If each question object has a `category` property you can use it when presenting the data and also for calculating the totals to determine the category scores.

```
const questions = [
  {
    category: "energy",
    question: "In summer, the temperature of your AC ?",
    answers: [
      { text: "+26℃", score: 5 },
      { text: "20-25℃", score: 3 },
      { text: "16-20℃", score: 1 },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "energy",
    question: "Will you turn off the screen when you are not using your PC ?",
    answers: [
      { text: "Often", score: 5 },
      { text: "Sometimes", score: 3 },
      { text: "Rarely", score: 1 }
    ]
  },
];
```

You can use the `filter` function to only present the questions for a particular category.

```
var categoryFilterMaker = function(category) {
  return function(obj) { 
    return obj.category === category
  }
}

// Create a filter for the 'energy' category
var energyFilter = categoryFilterMaker('energy');

// Filter the questions
questions.filter(energyFilter);
```

You could add a property to each object to record the selected answer or its score.

The map, reduce and filter functions are chainable so you can use them to get the scores in whatever format you require.